# Touch Detection in subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I have a view in which I have a scroll view.I want to detect touch began,moved etc. methods.I used these methods.These methods work fine outside the scroll view but doesn't work inside the scrollview.Tell me why it isn't working and what is the solution.

Comment: have you add `scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;`

Comment: @Unknown, `userInteractionEnabled=YES` by default for `UIScrollView`.

Comment: yeah,user interaction is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **Subclass UIView** (as MyUIView)and Implement the touch delegate.

Then Add MyUIView to UIScrollView

Eg:

```
   @interface MyUIView : UIViewController {

   }
   @end

  @implementation MyUIView

      //implement touch delegate here
   }
```

***Add this line in your main view***

```
MyUIView *myUIView = [[MyUIView alloc] init];
myUIView.userIntarctionEnabled = YES;
[yourScrollView addSubView:myUIView.view];
```

**Note**: you can use [UIGustures](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/event-handling/gestures-recognizers-tap-pinchzoom-rotate-swipe-pan-long-press.html)  instead of sub-classing. The UIGestureRecognizer class is available to help with detecting and responding to the various UI gestures common on iOS devices

Comment: The class is view controller and I did the same by storyboard.

Comment: I used the UIGustures too but they won't be able to help me in detecting moved,began etc.

Comment: then subclass UIViewController and UIViewController.view as subview of ur scroller

Answer (score 0):

Use  `convertPoint: toView:` method.

```
CGPoint *point = [yourView convertPoint:touchPoint toView:yourScrollView];
```